How to get reference to instance of class overriding the provider in Nest.js Testing Module?
I'm creating an environment for integration testing of Nest.js app. To mock external dependencies, I'm overriding the HttpService provider with my custom class, to be precise, with a facade class hiding more complex logic behind it self.
I need to obtain a reference to the object to be able to change its state, regardless of the app flow, and simulate certain edge cases for testing.
Here is a snippet of my code from tests setup:
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      .overrideProvider(HttpService)
      .useClass(HttpServiceMockFacade)
      .compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

What I have already tried:
1.This doesn't working because
Nest could not find HttpServiceMockFacade element (this provider does not exist in the current context) 
    const httpMockFacade = await moduleFixture.resolve<HttpServiceMockFacade>(
      HttpServiceMockFacade,
    );


The same as above

    const httpMockFacade = moduleFixture.get<HttpServiceMockFacade>(
      HttpServiceMockFacade,
    );


Trying to get is as HttpService and casting to HttpServiceMockFacade by using unknown as an intermediary since HttpServiceMockFacade implements more methods than HttpService and can’t be cast directly) doesn't helping either. It does not throw error but i guess the casting goes wrong.

    const httpMockFacade = moduleFixture.get<HttpService>(
      HttpService,
    ) as unknown as HttpServiceMockFacade;

    console.log(`httpMockFacade ${JSON.stringify(httpMockFacade, null, 2)}`);
    // prints: httpMockFacade {}

How is exactly the following supposed to work?
overrideProvider(HttpService)
      .useClass(HttpServiceMockFacade)

I was expecting that calling HttpService would just result in returning HttpServiceMockFacase. Also it worth noting that this HttpServiceMockFacase is working correctly. Only problem lies in accessing the object and the overriding of HttpService is all good.

You generally need to get by the provider token, not by the actual implementation that you are injecting.
Same as how you inject it in constructors in your normal modules.
I usually get/resolve from the app and not directly from the module, not sure if this makes a difference here.
const httpService = app.get(HttpService);
// or 
const httpService = await app.resolve(HttpService);

// and then
httpService instanceof HttpServiceMockFacade // => should be true

You can then type cast it to your MockFacade or do an instanceof check if you need to access it directly.
